# How design a autoencoder architecture

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision, autoencoder

I would like to build an autoencoder (CNN) to learn a representation of my data.

I never built such a network and I have some experience in supervised learning (classification).

I would like to know if some good practices in training a classifier is also right for an autoencoder:

1. Does reference architecture exists like ResNet/Inception or something? If not, should I design manually layers?
2. Does transfer learning/fine tuning works for autoencoder (or is it better to train from scratch)?

Comment: second result on google: https://xifengguo.github.io/papers/ICONIP17-DCEC.pdf

Comment: Try reading the Keras blog!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are open source examples. Take a look at [here](https://github.com/nlintz/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/06_autoencoder.py) and [here](http://github.com/nlintz/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/06_autoencoder.ipynb).
About your second question, yes. There are numerous studies. For instance, take a look at [Supervised Representation Learning: Transfer Learning with Deep Autoencoders](https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/15/Papers/578.pdf).